# How Do I Copy Items With Source Folder Hierarchy Maintain & Where CreationTime As A Criteria?

Tags: powershell

I am copying PDF files to the destination folder. I needed to maintain the same folder structure as the source folder.

I managed to copy and maintain the folder structure but somehow it is not selecting based on my where creationtime criteria.

```cs
$archive_MonthlyStatement = "D:\Archives\Monthly_Statement"
$path2 = "D:\Temp\Test_Output\"

$scan_monthStatement = Get-ChildItem $archive_MonthlyStatement | Where-Object {
    (( $_.PSIsContainer ))
} | Where {
    $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-730)
} | Copy-Item -Destination "$path2" -Recurse -Container
```

Expected outcome:
Source folder:

```
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2015\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2016\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2017\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2018\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2019\pdf files
```

Destination folder:

```
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2015\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2016\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2017\pdf files
```

Actual outcome:
Destination folder:

```
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2015\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2016\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2017\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2018\pdf files
Archives\Reports\Branch1\2019\pdf files
```

Somehow it is copying all as long as the parent directory creation time is more than 730 days.

Comment: Check if the parent folder name is less than the current year minus one?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the parent folder creation time is 2015. Hence, more than 730 days.

Comment: I did not suggest to check the parent folders *creation time*.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers sorry i misunderstood your suggestion the first time. How do i check parent folder name less than current year minus 1?

Answer (score 0):

check the creationtime of each file and copy it.

```
$srcDir = "D:\Archives\Monthly_Statement"
$destDir = "D:\Temp\Test_Output"

Get-ChildItem $srcDir -Filter *.pdf -Recurse |
Where-Object CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-730) |
ForEach-Object {
    $destFile = [IO.FileInfo]::new($_.FullName.Replace($srcDir, $destDir))
    if($destFile.Exists) { return }
    if(!$destFile.Directory.Exists) { $destFile.Directory.Create() }
    $_.CopyTo($destFile)
}
```

Comment: i encounter the error "Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method named 'new'"